# How can I host multiple Service Fabric Actor Types inside a single service?

Tags: actor, azure-service-fabric

I've read [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/) that is should be possible to host tightly coupled ActorTypes within the same service but I can't seem to find any documentation on exactly how to do it.

I thought it might I need to create my own instance of the ActorService and pass the context into it but I don't seen to be able to find the right API's from the document.

Does anyone have an example they could share ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sort of but not really. You can have multiple actor types in the same *application*. It looks like they're in the same service in Visual Studio, but they're actually deployed as separate services. Bear with me for a minute if you will..

So you can register multiple actors like this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor2>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

Great, I have multiple actor types. This works and you can just do that.

But you want know *how* it works! Well, that's just a simplified version of this:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor1>(
            (context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType, () => new Actor1())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<Actor2>(
            (context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType, () => new Actor2())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
}
```

This is more telling of what's actually happening, because you see here I now have two services. So what's going on?

The secret is in the ActorRuntime. It does a little more work than ServiceRuntime (where you register Reliable Services normally). The Actor framework build process does some magic on your behalf to configure a service type and a default service instance inside your application *for each actor type*. You can see this in your ApplicationManifest.xml, where the build tools sets up default services for you:

```
<DefaultServices>
  <Service Name="Actor1ActorService" GeneratedIdRef="3262c188-3eee-44c5-9d1e-d2c2a2685f89|Persisted">
     <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="Actor1ActorServiceType" TargetReplicaSetSize="[Actor1ActorService_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[Actor1ActorService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
        <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[Actor1ActorService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
     </StatefulService>
  </Service>
  <Service Name="Actor2ActorService" GeneratedIdRef="1bc66d2c-0479-4bb2-a9aa-3254030506f1|Persisted">
     <StatefulService ServiceTypeName="Actor2ActorServiceType" TargetReplicaSetSize="[Actor2ActorService_TargetReplicaSetSize]" MinReplicaSetSize="[Actor2ActorService_MinReplicaSetSize]">
        <UniformInt64Partition PartitionCount="[Actor2ActorService_PartitionCount]" LowKey="-9223372036854775808" HighKey="9223372036854775807" />
     </StatefulService>
  </Service>
```

As an example, if I take the two actor types I have defined above and deploy that application, here is the result:

[image: actor services]

These are actually separate service instances in the application, and each is of a different service type, all of which is automatically generated for you:

[image]

And of course, because they're different service instances, they'll be distribute across the cluster as you would normally expect:

[image]

I'll go update that doc.

Comment: So we were hoping to achieve by running them in the same service was to minimise the performance overhead of Actor1 and Actor2 communicating with each other; especially if they are hosted on different nodes as in your example. What else could we do to minimise the overhead of their inter-actor communications

Comment: Well, the service partition replicas are distributed across nodes but you can control which partition your actors go in by manipulating the Actor IDs (see here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-platform/#service-fabric-partition-concepts-for-actors). You can eliminate network traffic but it still crosses process boundaries so you still incur serialization costs.

Comment: Cool, that's what we were thinking, so if we keep the objects small to tiny then that's as good as it gets. We should also consider this when we decide what's an Actor and what's a library I guess.

Comment: Yeah, think about units of distribution and scale. Each actor should be free to roam around in the cluster. If there's a piece of functionality that you need to keep close for speed, that sounds more like a library to me.

Comment: Is it possible to have different partition counts per actor type? Or should they be exactly the same?