# Cannot register two Actors within one ActorRuntime in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have a single Service Fabric Actor Service. This creates two projects, `ActorService` and `ActorService.Interfaces`.

ActorService.Interfaces contains interface for the root actor, called `IRootActor`. ActorService itself contains `RootActor` and `IChildActor`, `ChildActor`. Both of the interfaces implement `IActor`, both of the classes inherit `Actor` and implement their respective interfaces. I register these actors from within Program.cs like this:

```
ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<ChildActor>(
   (context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType, () => container.Resolve<ChildActor>()))
   .GetAwaiter()
   .GetResult();

ActorRuntime.RegisterActorAsync<RootActor>(
   (context, actorType) => new ActorService(context, actorType, () => container.Resolve<RootActor.Factory>()(context)))
   .GetAwaiter()
   .GetResult();

Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

The call to `container.Resolve<RootActor.Factory>()(context)` returns `RootActor` instance.

When I call

```
IRootActory proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IRootActor>(new ActorId(id), actorServiceUri);
proxy.Method(data);
```

everything goes fine. Aforementioned `RootActor.Method` method does two things in a single loop, creates child actor and calls it's method:

```
IChildActor proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IChildActor>(new ActorId(otherId), sameActorServiceUri);
proxy.OtherMethod(transformedData);
```

And here comes the problem. Upon `proxy.OtherMethod` call, essentially this wild exception appears:

> HResult=-2146232969 
>   Message=No MethodDispatcher is found for interface
>   id '230348154' Source=Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors

Am I doing something wrong here? Taking into account [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146843/how-can-i-host-multiple-service-fabric-actor-types-inside-a-single-service), I thought it was possible to create two actors from one service...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. For anyone out there struggling, the problem was with the actor service URI.
I have wrongly assumed that both actors share service URI. As it was mentioned in [the link I mentioned in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146843/how-can-i-host-multiple-service-fabric-actor-types-inside-a-single-service), The actors get actually hosted separately. If you take a look inside `ServiceManifest.xml`, you'll find two `Extension` xml nodes, both of them named as `__GeneratedServiceType__`. All it takes is to change the service name part accoring to child `DefaultService` xml node, so in this example it would be most probably `ChildActorService`. Gosh, that sounds very inapropriate.

To wrap things up, the setup and configuration of anything in Service Fabric is rather complicated. However, VS tries it's best to help you out. Sometimes you don't even expect it, and here essentially lies the root of the evil. If you don't know what to look for, you won't look for it.

Answer (score 1):

The actors are registered fine, while connecting to them using ActorProxy, you need to specify the correct service name if you are specifying the service name. You can omit the service name and specify the ApplciationName instead and Actor Framework figures out the correct service name for the Actor. Please see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt694503.aspx

Comment: Isn't the comment about figuring out the name imprecise? The link you posted mentions that the name is derived from an interface the actor implements, but cannot be inferred when actor implements more interfaces...